# Bincrafters modular Conan packages and the cmake_find_package generator

Tags: cmake, conan

I have run into an issue using the 1.69.0 version of Boost conan packages built by bincrafters. I do not have problems using other conan packages like libcurl and zlib.

I have written a conanfile.txt like so:

```
[requires]
boost_context/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable
boost_coroutine/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable
boost_date_time/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable
boost_filesystem/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable
boost_iostreams/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable
boost_program_options/1.69.0@bincrafters/stable
expat/2.2.5@bincrafters/stable
libcurl/7.56.1@bincrafters/stable

[generators]
cmake_find_package
```

and in CMakeLists.txt, I am trying to link like so:

```
target_link_libraries(
  llcommon PUBLIC
  expat::expat
  zlib::zlib
  boost_coroutine::boost_coroutine
  boost_context::boost_context
  )
```

Expat and Zlib are found and link without a hitch. For the boost* libraries though, I receive the following error from CMake:

```
CMake Error at llcommon/CMakeLists.txt:243 (add_library):
  Target "llcommon" links to target "boost_context::boost_context" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

Is there something about the bincrafters modular Boost packages that I am missing? or can I not use the `conan_find_package` generator with them?

Comment: Did you already tried to use `boost::boost_coroutine`?

Comment: Yes, I tried `boost::boost_coroutine` as well as `boost::coroutine` to no avail.

Comment: Double checked in the generated `Findboost_coroutine.cmake` and the target is defined as `boost_coroutine::boost_coroutine` as well. So I think that part is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I did not update the `find_package` call.

```
find_package(boost_coroutine)
find_package(boost_context)
```

was missing

Apparently, I need to pay attention to what the CMake error is telling me next time.